# How to resolve the M2SS0020( Index Key exceeded) in SSMA

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

I am migrating my database from `MySQL` to `SQL Server` using `SSMA`. During Conversion SSMA throws an error `'index key size exceeded'`. I searched for some solution but still did not understand how to resolve it. I am new to database conversion so I don't know much about it. Can anyone help me out with this. Following indexes are responsible for error :

```
KEY `feed_nid`  (`feed_nid`) , 
KEY `lookup_url`  (`entity_type`, `id`, `feed_nid`, `url` (128)) , 
KEY `lookup_guid`  (`entity_type`, `id`, `feed_nid`, `guid` (128)) , 
KEY `global_lookup_url`  (`entity_type`, `url` (128)) , 
KEY `global_lookup_guid`  (`entity_type`, `guid` (128)) ,
```

Comment: Add the mysql CREATE TABLE DDL to your question.

Comment: Please check the field mapping configuration in the SSMA